# How to ensure that while a user is scrolling, it keeps on checking how far it has scrolled?

Tags: jquery

I am using throttle to call a function where I am checking how far a user has scrolled. If a user has scrolled above 115px, then I am adding a class to the body. It works except if a user keeps on scrolling fast on a **mobile/tablet device**, the class is only added when the user stops scrolling. *I suspect the scroll is not checked unless a user stops scrolling.* How to ensure that while a user is scrolling, it keeps on checking how far it has scrolled?

```
var throttled = _.throttle(myFunc, 50);
$(window).on('scroll', throttled);

function myFunc() {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll >= 115) {
      $('body').addClass('header-fixed');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put event listener for scroll like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    // get the scroll value
    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(scrollPosition);
    // Put some check for the scroll position and fix the header
    });
});
```

[JSfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/7/)